# Layers not showing up together in ArcGIS even when in same coordinate system

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, layers, overlapping-features

I have two layers in my project and both are being set to same coordinate system. But still they both son't show up together. Can someone please help me out in this.

```
Projected Coordinate System:    NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_14N
Projection: Transverse_Mercator
False_Easting:  500000.00000000
False_Northing: 0.00000000
Central_Meridian:   -99.00000000
Scale_Factor:   0.99960000
Latitude_Of_Origin: 0.00000000
Linear Unit:    Meter
```

---

```
Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_North_American_1983
Datum:  D_North_American_1983
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! You say both layers are in the same SRS and then list two different ones without further explanation. Please edit your question and clarify what you want to ask.

Comment: When you say 'set' are you reprojecting the datasets, so that both are in the same coordinate system? Both datasets must be in the same coordinate system in order to see them in the same location. The listed coordinate systems above are different.

Comment: In addition, either or both of your layers may have a projection 'defined', but not actually projected. If these are shapefiles, one quick and dirty way is to delete the <name_of_shapefile>.prj file, then define and project the shapefiles to the same coordinate system. Caveat - if the layers were developed in different cs's, their units may be different, so the above won't work. In that case you'll have to define/project them to their correct cs. There are a lot of resources you can google to help determine what the cs should be.

Answer (score 2):

What I do usually is to restart ArcMap and load the **last** dataset first. 
The dataset you loaded first should be loaded second. You can proceed and load the two datasets in separated windows, overlay a basemap to see if the points fall in their expected location.

In addition, if one is a dataset from the field, I would recommend you keep the GCS instead of projecting it for the time being. Critically, check your projection systems for the two datasets, i.e. GCS vs PCS.